# Visual bug on main site profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's an odd graphical glitch on my profile page, but it only appears on the Gaming main site. I have not been able to reproduce it on Meta nor on any other SE site.

[image: profile tabs overlapping]

This blue box appears behind a number of tabs and I think it's the "next badge progress" box but I can't be sure.

Comment: Also on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/youve-earned-badge-panel-layouts-are-broken).

Comment: This looks like it was fixed as of November 9th as per the [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316061/179041) post.

Comment: ^I did actually attempt to post that as an answer. Seems I got bit by the [too trivial to post as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/179041) algorithm